# Oracle startup not possible - ORA-00845: MEMORY_TARGET not supported on this system - but memory size seems to be fine

Tags: oracle, memory-management, shared-memory

We get an `ORA-00845: MEMORY_TARGET not supported on this system` on startup.

However, `df -h` shows

```
tmpfs                 7,9G  4,0K  7,9G   1% /dev/shm.
```

Which indicates that there is more than enough memory availabe. Any ideas what could be the cause?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You might be using **Automatic Memory Management (AMM)**.

AMM uses two initialization parameters:

- **MEMORY_TARGET**
- **MEMORY_MAX_TARGET**

The shared memory file system should have enough space to accommodate the MEMORY_TARGET and MEMORY_MAX_TARGET values.

To verify:

```
SQL> show parameter memory

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
hi_shared_memory_address             integer     0
memory_max_target                    big integer 6096M
memory_target                        big integer 6096M
shared_memory_address                integer     0
```

In **UNIX/Linux**, you will have to set the **shared memory file system** accordingly.

**Verify:**

```
df -h /dev/shm
```

**Set:**

```
mount -t tmpfs shmfs -o size=<some_value_in_number_with_size> /dev/shm
```

*For example*,

```
mount -t tmpfs shmfs -o size=4096m /dev/shm
```

Comment: I get this, which looks defective: `SQL> show parameter memory
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0`

Comment: You need to `startup`

Comment: well, but when I do startup, I get `MEMORY_TARGET not supported on this system` - Going round in circles

Comment: Did you increase the `MEMORY_TARGET` in OS? See http://oracle4ryou.blogspot.in/2013/05/ora-00845-memorytarget-not-supported-on.html

Comment: I cant increase MEMORY_TARGET because when I do somehting like `alter system set memory_target=1200m scope=spfile;` I get `ORA-01034: ORACLE not available`

Comment: I didn't tell you to set it at database level, you need to increase the size for `/dev/shm` at OS level. The issue is plain and simple, your OS /`dev/shm` doesn't have enough space to hold MEMORY_TARGET values of database.

Comment: How would the `/etc/fstab` look? Is there a difference between *shmfs* and *tmpfs* ?

Answer (score 4):

Error Cause:
The new Automatic Memory Management functionality uses /dev/shm on Linux for SGA and PGA management. The errors occur if either MEMORY_TARGET or MEMORY_MAX_TARGET is configured larger than the configured /dev/shm size, or if /dev/shm is mounted incorrectly.

SOLUTION:
Please confirm that ORACLE_HOME is set correctly. This error sometimes happens when it is not set correctly.

Make sure that the /dev/shm size is configured large enough, like in:
mount -t tmpfs shmfs -o size=7g /dev/shm

Note:
You should check with your System Administrator what the "best" size for /dev/shm is, based on what has been reported in the alert file.

Also, many best practices now suggest disabling AMM especially in Exa* Engineered boxes that have larger memory capability and can use Huge / Large pages.
This is because AMM and Huge / Large pages are mutually exclusive and overall performance will be better using Huge pages

Make sure that the df output shows the correct /dev/shm configuration when using Oracle on the system:

```
$ df -k
Filesystem 1K-blocks Used Available Use% Mounted on
...
shmfs 6291456 832356 5459100 14% /dev/shm
```

Answer (score 3):

An easy solution is just to add space to `/dev/shm fs`.

```
# mount -t tmpfs shmfs -o size=5g /dev/shm
```

For more concepts and details, see the blog post [ORA-00845: MEMORY_TARGET not supported on this system](https://ora-data.blogspot.in/2017/02/ora-00845-memorytarget-not-supported-on.html).

Comment: # sudo mount -t tmpfs shmfs -o size=5g /dev/shm

Answer (score 0):

- Reduce the value for the memory_target parameter
- Increase the temporary memory allocation on the server.

e.g

## umount tmpfs

## mount -t tmpfs shmfs -o size=1500m /dev/shm

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting the same error while starting the database. I # out memory_target parameter in my pfile and then tried again and it worked.
Now, i was able to startup the database.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? What do you mean by `# out`?

Comment: I mean to say comment, I just commented memory_target parameter with it's value in pfile. Now, it will take space/sizing automatically.

Answer (score 0):

this error comes when memory setting of oracle is high for the tmpfs area
for example

if memory parameters like this:

```
*.memory_max_target=20G
*.memory_target=0
*.sga_max_size=20G
*.sga_target=15G
*.pga_aggregate_target=5G
```

and tmpfs size is 15G

when you issue startup you get the error ora-00845 
you should set tmpfs size over the max memory value 
In this situtation max memory parameter is set to 20G 
so you set tmpfs size in /etc/fstab file for example 25G

```
...
...
tmpfs   /dev/shm   tmpfs  defaults,size25G 0 0
...
...
```

and then remount the tmpfs file system

```
#mount -o remount /dev/shm
```

then your database be able to startup

Answer (score 0):

Did you change the RAM for the VM if you are using any? If you did then it must be the issue. Increase the RAM to the same or more value as before and try again.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.